# Updating UITableView height and data dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, dynamic

I am implementing a search-as-you-type functionality but having issues with dynamically updating the number of rows in the UITableView. I use a UISearchBar and trigger a search after the user has typed in three letters.

I query the search results through an API which fetches the data asynchronously. This is how I get the results and update the data source array

```
if let text = searchBar.text {
    if text.count >= minSearchStartCriteria {

        let tableX:CGFloat = 0
        let tableY:CGFloat = searchBar.frame.maxY
        let tableWidth:CGFloat = view.frame.width
        var tableHeight:CGFloat = 0

        // remove the tap recognizer so that the tap on the uitableview
        // can be captured
        if let tapRecognizer = tapRecognizer,
            let recognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
            if recognizers.count > 0 {
                view.removeGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
            }
        }

        // create the UITableView
        if searchResultsTable == nil {

            searchResultsTable = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: tableX, y: tableY , width: tableWidth, height: tableHeight))

            if let searchResultsTable = searchResultsTable {
                searchResultsTable.delegate = self
                searchResultsTable.dataSource = self
                searchResultsTable.register(SearchResultTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "searchResultTableCell")
                view.addSubview(searchResultsTable)
            }
        }

        // update the search results
        if let p = onlineSearchPresenter {
            p.getSearchResults(request: text) { (results) in
                self.searchResults = results
            }
            tableHeight = CGFloat(searchResults.count * 44)
            searchResultsTable?.frame = CGRect(x: tableX, y: tableY, width: tableWidth, height: tableHeight)
            searchResultsTable?.reloadData()
        }
    } else {
        // If there is less than "minSearchStartCriteria" letters, remove the table view
        searchResults.removeAll()
        searchResultsTable?.removeFromSuperview()
        searchResultsTable = nil
    }
}
```

If I type in "abcd" the search returns 10 results, hence my UITableView is created with 10 rows. No issues here. Then, if I carry on adding letters and narrowing down the search, I am returned less number of results, say only 4. I checked from the debugger, it shows the correct number of results within the `searchResults` array, but `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` stills attempts to fetch a result from index 4, which is out of range for an array having only four items in it.

It appears I need to let the UITableView know the data source array has been updated so that it would update its indexing. I suspect the issue lies within the asynchronous nature of updating the results array but cannot figure out what the exact issue is.

How can I get this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you think issue is due to "asynchronous nature of updating the results array" you should use debouncing.

using debouncing you can  limit how often function can fire by waiting a certain amount of time before executing it.

https://gist.github.com/DoubleREW/567f5e67262f1de781f4f9164235d4e9

https://bradfol.com/how-can-i-debounce-a-method-call-in-swift-4/